# Chain the request to struts action on another namespace

Tags: jakarta-ee, struts2, struts, struts-config

In my struts application, I have 2 namespaces named 'a' and 'b' and defined action 'process' for each namespace.

Now, in some cases I have to chain the request from action 'process' in namespace 'a' to action 'process' in namespace 'b'. However I don't know how to do this in struts.xml. How do I chain these requests to another namespace?

My struts configuration looks like following:

```
<package name="testa" extends="struts-default, json-default" namespace="/a">
    <action name="process" class="com.khoinguyen.action.ProcessAction" method="handleResponseA">
        <result type="chain" name="return_b">
            <param name="actionName">b/process</param>
        </result>
        <result name="success">completea.jsp</result>
    </action>
</package>
<package name="testb" extends="struts-default, json-default" namespace="/b">
    <action name="process" class="com.khoinguyen.action.ProcessAction" method="handleResponseB">        
        <result name="success">completeb.jsp</result>
    </action>
</package>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `<param name="namespace">` inside `chain` type result. You can see the official documentation about this type result in [Struts2 official documentation](http://struts.apache.org/2.1.6/docs/chain-result.html) to see more information about it.

In your case:

```
<package name="testa" extends="struts-default, json-default" namespace="/a">
    <action name="process" class="com.khoinguyen.action.ProcessAction" method="handleResponseA">
        <result type="chain" name="return_b">
             <param name="namespace">/b</param>
             <param name="actionName">process</param>
        </result>
        <result name="success">completea.jsp</result>
    </action>
</package>
```

Comment: It works with your suggestion, however in method handleResponseB correspond to action after chained, I cannot get the namespace by method `ServletActionContext.getActionMapping().getNamespace();`

It always returns '/', while expectation is '/b' instead of

Comment: @KhoiNguyen I face to this problem before. Try this: check if the name of the namespace is inside the action name with `ServletActionContext.getActionMapping().getName()`.

Comment: the name always returns 'process' value due to it's same action name, only namespace is different

Answer (score 0):

Please use result `type="redirectAction"` instead of result `type="chain"`